# Too few arguments to function.. What does it mean where do I go wrong?

Tags: c, function

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int validate(int low, int high);

int main ()
{
    //Declare Variables
    float strength, speed, defense, intelligence;
    float strengthRatio, speedRatio, defenseRatio, intelligenceRatio;
    int strength_F, speed_F, defense_F, intelligence_F;
    float sum;
    int luck;
    float PStrength=10;
    float PDefense=20;
    float PIntelligence=40;
    int PHP=10;
    float EStrength=30;
    float EDefense=40;
    float EIntelligence=25;
    int EHP=10;
    int sel;
    float attackp;
    float magicp;
    int low=1;
    int high=3;
    int Valid_Selection;

    //Clear Screen
    system("cls");

    //Display Logo
    printf("+----------------------+\n");
    printf("|                      |\n");
    printf("|     CODE QUEST       |\n");
    printf("|                      |\n");
    printf("+----------------------+\n\n");

    //Main Menu
    printf("--Main Menu--\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("1 - New Game\n");
    printf("2 - Load Game\n");
    printf("3 - Exit\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Selection: \n\n");

    // Validate user input using a function
    Valid_Selection = validate(int low,int high);

    // Game_Selection = validate();

    printf ("Character Creation \n");
    printf ("Please enter your desired stats for your character:\n");
    printf ("\n");
    printf ("Enter strength: ");
    scanf  ("%f", &strength);
    printf ("Enter speed: ");
    scanf  ("%f", &speed);
    printf ("Enter defense: ");
    scanf  ("%f", &defense);
    printf ("Enter intelligence: ");
    scanf  ("%f", &intelligence);

    // Calculate the sum of all attributes
    sum = strength + speed + defense + intelligence;

    // Calculate ratios for each attribute
    strengthRatio = strength / sum;
    speedRatio = speed / sum;
    defenseRatio = defense / sum;
    intelligenceRatio = intelligence / sum;

    // Calculate the final Stats as whole number
    strength_F = strengthRatio * 100;
    speed_F = speedRatio * 100;
    defense_F = defenseRatio * 100;
    intelligence_F = intelligenceRatio * 100;

    // Calculate the player's luck
    luck = (int)sum % 30;

    // Create an empty line for beauty
    printf ("\n");

    // Display to the user the finalized player stats
    printf ("Your player's final stats are:");
    printf ("\n");
    printf ("Strength: %d\n", strength_F);
    printf ("Speed: %d\n", speed_F);
    printf ("Defense: %d\n", defense_F);
    printf ("Intelligence: %d\n", intelligence_F);
    printf ("Luck: %d\n", luck);

    // Display "Battle Starts"
    printf("Battle Start!\n\n");

    while (PHP >= 0 && EHP >= 0) {
        //Display user and enemy HP and asks user which attack execute
        printf("Your HP: %d, Enemy HP: %d\n", PHP, EHP);
        printf("1 - Attack Power\n");
        printf("2 - Magic Power\n");
        scanf("%d",&sel);

        //Option 1, Option 2
        if (sel == 1) {
            attackp = (PStrength / EDefense) * 5;
            EHP = EHP - attackp;
            printf("You attacked the enemy\n");
        }
        else {
            magicp = (PIntelligence / EIntelligence) * 5;
            EHP = EHP - magicp;
            printf("You bewitched the enemy!\n");
        }

        // Enemy reaction based on his own HP
        if (EHP <= 0)
            printf("You won!\n");
        else {
            attackp = (EStrength / PDefense) * 5;
            PHP = PHP - attackp;
            printf("The enemy attacked you\n");
        }

        // Indicates if user lost the game
        if (PHP <= 0)
            printf("You lost!\n");

        printf("\n");
    }

  return 0;

    }

    int validate(int low, int high) {
    int s;

    do{
    scanf("%d", s);
    if (s<1 || s>3)
        printf("invalid Input, try again:");
    } while (s<1 || s>3);

    return s;
    }

    int validate(int low, int high) {
        int selection;

        do {
        scanf("%d", selection);
        if (selection <0 || selection>3)
            printf("Invalid Input, try again: ");
        } while (0<selection<4);

        return selection;
    }
```

I want the user to enter a number between 1 and 3 and I need the validate function to verify it. Can anyone explain me where I go wrong please? what is the proper way to do it?

Comment: You aren't calling the function properly.  You have to supply actual parameters to it, not write `int low, int high`.

Comment: As @LukePark said.  More specifically, the variable's *types* (i.e. `int`) are not part of their *names*.  You specify the types when you declare the function, but not when you call it.

Comment: You have two definitions for the `validate` function; that's not going to work.  And the call should simply be `Valid_Selection = validate(low,high);`

Comment: I did some corrections and now when I compile I get an error saying redefinition of "validate".. here's the code of the function itself:

Comment: int validate(int low, int high) {
        int selection;

        do {
        scanf("%d", selection);
        if (selection <0 || selection>3)
            printf("Invalid Input, try again: ");
        } while (0<selection<4);

        return selection;
 }

Comment: **Massive bugs**: not testing the return values from `scanf`. You **must** test these; anything else is asking for surprises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `validate` must be called as:

```
//Validate user input using a functuion
Valid_Selection = validate(1, 3);
```

as your menu has choices between 1 and 3, and your function should be:

```
int validate(int low, int high) {
int s=0;
char buf[128];

    do {
        if (fgets(buf,128,stdin)==0 || sscanf(buf, "%d", &s)!=1 || (s<low || s>high))
            printf("invalid Input, try again:");
        else
            return s;
    } while (1);
}
```

and there can be only one function with that name, so remove the second one. Btw, `while (0<selection<4)` in the second one, must be written as: `while (0<selection && selection<4)`.

Edit: note the check for the return value of `sscanf`. It tells us whether `sscanf` could read the value type specified, `%d`, and note to pass the *address* of the integer where to store the result. The initialization of `s` to zero ensures the while loop will not be exited while there was invalid input.

Edit: fixed Chux's comment to consume stdin.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed I wrote the function twice and never got rid of the original one. Anyway, when I rub and I enter a wrong value the program crashes.. Does it have to be a problem of the loop ?

Comment: Ah, I see...fixed in the solution.

Comment: How ? I am not understanding what you mean :/

Comment: this is my code for the loop: int validate(int low, int high) {
        int selection;

        do {
        scanf("%d", selection);
        if (selection < low || selection > high)
            printf("Invalid Input, try again: ");
        } while (selection > low || selection < high);

        return selection;
 }

Comment: Try again. I think I was still editing the solution.

Comment: I just did... It doesn't matter what value I insert it always crashes

Comment: Use a debugger to check where it crashes. `validate` seems ok like this.

Comment: 1) `if (scanf("%d", &s)!=1 || (s<low || s>high))` can easily lead to an infinite loop should user enter something non-numeric - which stays in `stdin` even though repetitive `scanf("%d"` calls.  Something needs to read the offending input  2) Nit: Loop condition `while (s<low || s>high);` is also problematic as code is comparing to `s` whose value is not known.  (consider `scanf()` returning `EOF` due to input error leaves `s` in an unknown value.) "The initialization of `s` to zero ensures the while loop will not be exited while there was invalid input." is not true.

Comment: @Chux, thanks. Agree with 1): must read stdin. I do not agree with 2): if `scanf` can't read/convert, `s` will be unaffected.

Comment: 2) looks like a good SO question.  Using `gets()` - unavailable in C11 will not earn many raves - perhaps `fgets()`?