# sscanf unconverted fields are unaffected?

Tags: c, scanf

If `sscanf` must convert a field, and it fails, will the field's corresponding variable remain unaffected? This question was raised in a comment in a recent solution I posted:

```
int validate(int low, int high) {
int s=0;
char buf[128];

    do {
        if (fgets(buf,128,stdin)==0 || sscanf(buf, "%d", &s)!=1 || (s<low || s>high))
            printf("invalid Input, try again:");
    } while (s<low || s>high);
    return s;
}
```

In this example, `s` is intialized to zero and it is assumed it remains zero while `sscanf` cannot convert an integer value from the input. This ensuers the loop is not exited while invalid input has been entered (assuming `low` is larger than zero).

From VC2008 documentation "*`sscanf`...returns the number of fields successfully converted and assigned*" which seems to imply it internally converts the input and after successful conversion performs the assignment. That in turn would imply that `s` is unaffected if `sscanf` could not convert the input.

Comment: fgets() only returns NULL on EOF (or error), so staying in the loop will not be usefull. (BTW adding a space to the `" %d"` format string could possibly help)

Comment: @wildplasser: sscanf automatically skips whitespace before %d. How does adding a space to the format change anything?

Comment: Note that the poor user faced with this code gets told "you did it wrong" but gets no hint about what is right.  You should help them: `printf("Invalid input (range %d..%d).  Try again: ", low, high);` would at least let them know what's expected.

Comment: @rici: I stand corrected. The other point (fgets() returning NULL) still stands.

Comment: Pretty sure that the answer is **Yes**.

Comment: Detail: ["This question was raised in a comment "](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33113457/too-few-arguments-to-function-what-does-it-mean-where-do-i-go-wrong/33113646#comment54045220_33113646) refereed to `scanf()`, not `sscanf()` as posted here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If `sscanf` must convert a field, and it fails, will the field's corresponding variable remain unaffected?

The standard does not say so explicitly, but it does seem to follow from the step-by-step description of the behavior of the `scanf()` family of functions.  In particular:

> Except in the case of a `%` specifier, the input item [...] is converted to a type appropriate to the conversion specifier.  If the input item is not a matching sequence, the execution of the directive fails: this condition is a matching failure.  Unless assignment suppression was indicated by a `*`, the result of the conversion is placed in the object pointed to by the first argument following the `format` argument that has not already received a conversion result.

I think it's pretty hard to interpret that other than as saying that first the input is converted, and then, if conversion is successful, it is assigned.  It follows that if conversion fails, the pointed-to object is not modified (by *that* conversion specifier -- it could have been modified by an earlier one if arguments are duplicated or if they alias each other).

Thus, I think your code should be expected to behave as you anticipated.